# what is a good APR when applying for micro loan online?

Tags: loans

I found an online loan company offering 7% APR with no credit history.Is it good or bad APR?

Comment: This would certainly depend on locale, but beyond that, answers are probably a matter of opinion.

Comment: For what country?

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is a good APR if you're putting down no collateral. In fact, I'd be rather suspicious of such a low rate with no credit history. What is the term of the loan?